# Key of Object is One of Array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I preserve that the returned object's keys are set by the incoming array

```
function f<T extends string, U = { [K in T]?: boolean }> (keys: T[]): U {
  const out: U = {} as U
  for (let key of keys) {
    out[key] = true
  }
  return out
}

f(['one', 'two'])['one'] // good
f(['one', 'two'])['three'] // throws error
```

I get the following error

```
Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'U'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the extra type parameter `U` breaks things here. Firstly `U = { [K in T]?: boolean }` defines a default for the type parameter `U` but does not constrain `U` in any way so it could be any type, so inside the function ts can't really say anything about `U`. You can just use the mapped type without the extra type parameter:

```
function f<T extends string> (keys: T[]) {
  const out = {} as { [K in T]?: boolean}
  for (let key of keys) {
    out[key] = true 
  }
  return out
}

f(['one', 'two'])['one'] // good
f(['one', 'two'])['three'] // throws error
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdEioAnGMAcwD5EAKAa0wE8iAuRNAbQF0AlIgDeAKESIICMojggoiALwiAvogCGJYYh4BpRFW58A-FwBGcOABtM6pCvHI45RjYUtWs4Ig9EhYiQk5KB4PPiVEChBMRwcJckwoEHIkYNEHUWAGHgByBEwcgBpEHKgAdzgcwQA6fMQAenrEaksCTOy8sALi0oqqgVyoAAsEgvDGyJG4MpJMcnJnUSA)